# Como melhorar o carregamento das entidades relacionadas usando LinqKit?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, code-first

Oi, 
Estou usando [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) para empilhar "Expression Predicates", com isso preciso fazer um "foreach" para fazer o Load das entidades relacionadas e isso está sendo muito custoso para aplicação pois para carregar 1000 registros está levando em média 4 minutos. Há alguma forma de agilizar esse processo de Load?

```
 public override IQueryable<Entity.Modelos.FluxoDeCaixa> Filtro(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Entity.Modelos.FluxoDeCaixa, bool>> expressao)
    {

        var query = from f in _contexto.FluxoDeCaixa.AsExpandable().Where(expressao)                        
                    from fu in _contexto.Funcionario.Where(x => x.PessoaId == f.FuncionarioId)
                    from pl in _contexto.PlanoDeContas.Where(x => x.PlanoDeContasId == f.PlanoDeContasId)
                    from pf in _contexto.PessoaFisica.Where(x => x.PessoaId == f.PessoaId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from pj in _contexto.PessoaJuridica.Where(x => x.PessoaId == f.PessoaId).DefaultIfEmpty()                                                
                    select f;

        foreach (var f in query)
        {
            _contexto.Entry(f)
            .Reference(r => r.PlanoDeContas)
            .Load();

            _contexto.Entry(f)
                .Reference(r => r.Funcionario)
                .Load();

            _contexto.Entry(f)
                .Reference(r => r.Pessoa)
                .Load();
        }


        return query;
    }
```